# AS3 getDefinitionByName is not a function

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm getting an AS3  error thrown at me when I try to set the text of a dynamic textfield to the text of another dynamic textfield in a movieclip.

here is my code:

```
repairMachine.screen.gotoAndStop(5);
repairMachine.screen.brandName.text = repairMachine.screen.getDefinitionByName(whichBrand).text;
```

The second line is where the error occurs.

brandName is a Dynamic TextField in a MovieClip called Screen(screen) which is inside the MovieClip RepairMachine(repairMachine).

Here is where I set whichbrand:

```
whichBrand = "brand" + ((repairMachine.screen.selectionArea.y - 6) / 22);
```

This code works and I am successfully tracing whichBrand as the correct instance names.

My question now is: Why am I getting Error #1006 getDefinitionByName is not a function.
And how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Yours,

Milan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`getDefinitionByName()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getDefinitionByName%28%29) does not belong to a class. Currently, you're attempting to call this function as a method of `repairMachine.screen`.

You should remove that, and have it called as a normal function:

```
getDefinitionByName(whichBrand);
```

That aside, you're trying to access instances. `getDefinitionByName()` is intended for fetching class definitions, not instances. You're after [`getChildByName()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildByName%28%29).

Comment: When I use getChildByName() I get the error implicit coercion between text and DisplayObject. Because I want to access the text inside the Dynamic Textfield with the instance name equal to whichBrand

Comment: @user2281425 `getChildByName()` returns a `DisplayObject`. You need to cast that to a `TextField`. Try `(getChildByName(whichBrand) as TextField).text;`

Comment: Now I get the error Filter operator not supported on type Screen.

Comment: I fixed it by placing the ( in front of everything. Thnx for your answer Marty.

Comment: @user2281425 Yes be sure to remember the opening parentheses; it encloses the result of your cast.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because getDefinitionByName is not a method of

```
repairMachine.screen
```

getDefinitionByName is in flash utils. so you have to use it like:

```
import flash.utils.*;

getDefinitionByName('my.fully.qualified.class.name');
```

You mention that whichBrand points to correct **instance** names.

The method getDefinitionByName is **not** for fetching **instances**.